# How to handle publish status after upgrade Tridion to SDL Web?

Tags: web8, upgrade, publishtransaction

I'm upgrading Tridion 2011 SP1 to SDL Web 8. 
I've done following steps.

- Copy DBs to new server and upgrade them.
- Newly install CMS(SDL Web 8) to new server, not upgrade Tridion 2011 SP1 itself.
- Setting up Topology Manager.

When publish pages and components, following operations are required.

1. Because Web site will be migrated to new Web/App server, we have to publish pages and components 
   which had been published to current Tridion 2011 environment.
2. Because Tridion_cm DB is copied, pages and components which had been published are marked as "Published",
   even though those are not published to new SDL Web 8 environment. 
   So it's required to remove the old publish status.

I'm planning following procedure to achieve those requirements.

1. Publish pages and components which are marked as "Published" to new environment one by one.
2. Remove old publish status by "Clear-TcmPublicationTarge" command.

In this situation, is above procedure good?

Are there another procedure?

Publishing pages and components one by one is time consuming and not accurate(there's a risk to miss to publish items).
So is it possible to do this work programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of Pages/Publications you might consider one of the following

- Using CoreService to automate the crawling, checking and publishing of assests
- Publishing Structure Group/Publication keeping "Republish Only" checked so that new items (unpublished items) are not published

[image: Republish only]

Comment: I'm afraid "Republish Only" is not applied if new publish target is created by Topology Manager, because the option is only available to publish target which page has already published to.

Comment: is there any way to set the reference of old targetType to new TargetType without publishing.publishing is a time consuming process.w e have all ready published file and CD database.